# FilterDefinition inside an existing BsonDocument

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-3.3

I'm trying to change a BsonDocument with more filters as shown bellow. First I parse a string like this:

```
BsonDocument query = BsonDocument.Parse (configObj.Mongo_dbquery);
```

And then I have more filters to apply. Is there any way I can include this filter inside BsonDocument?

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> dateFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte ("QueryDate", BsonValue.Create (startDate));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add The BsonElements manually using the text operators

```
{ field : { $gt : value } }
```

In BsonDocument would be

```
var doc = new BsonDocument("field", new BsonDocument("$gt", "value"));
```

Then it's just a case of appending this to your main BsonDocument